# salq and sarq in x86-64 Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am learning x86-64 assembly language with a textbook, and I am having difficulty understanding what specific lines of the code do.

```
the function in C that have the prototype

long doSth(long x, long y, long z):
```

and GCC generates the following assembly code;

```
#x->%rdi, y->%rsi, z->%rdx.

doSth:
subq    %rdx, %rsi
imulq   %rsi, %rdi
movq    %rsi, %rax
salq    $63, %rax
sarq    $63, %rax
xorq    %rdi, %rax
ret
```

I want to figire out how I would write C code that have an equivalent effect to the assembly code.

what I dont understand is that salq and sarq lines.

salq left shifts %rax by 63, but then in the next line sarq right shifts %rax by 63 back again.

So what is this doing in here? is it basically same as nothing happended?

How can I interpret these line so that I can write C code for these lines?

Thank you !

Comment: It certainly has an effect because it fills the register with the least significant bit. The `salq` moves the LSB into the sign bit, and `sarq` fills with the sign bit.

Comment: @Jester Thank you for your comment. so, for example(with 8bits for simplification), if %rax initially has 00000001, salq changes %rax into 10000000, and sarq changes that into 11111111? is this what you mean? Please let me know if I am getting this wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Jester Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Seems equivalent to `-(x&1)`, like and/neg instead of sal/sar.  Or since it's using this to conditionally NOT, maybe just NOT/TEST/CMOVZ.